# preposition for "research" [the verb]

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I would like to know the correct preposition for research when used with "**any topic**."

Should it be:

> It enables us to research *any topic* with ease.

Or:

> It enables us to research **into** *any topic* with ease.

Comment: We [don't include a preposition](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=researched+it%2Cresearched+into+it&year_start=1959&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) with the transitive usage ***to research a topic***. Just because the object in your example is modified by ***any*** doesn't affect this.

Comment: While the transitive usage is crisper, 'research into' is also acceptable: << **research into** (someone or something) ... 
To gather and study a large or dense amount of information about someone or something • _Scientists are researching into ways to treat cancer through gene therapy._ >> [[Farlex Dictionary of Idioms.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/researched+into)] It possibly connotes deeper / more thorough research than the simplex verb, 'into' bringing into play the container metaphor.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Even for the specific context you cited, the superfluous preposition has [next to no currency.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+researching+into+ways+to%2Care+researching+ways+to&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) And to be honest, I think your point about *possibly connotes deeper / more thorough research than the simplex verb* is just "post-hoc rationalisation" that sounds "plausible" if we start from the assumption that there ***is*** a potential semantic difference. But in reality I believe no such distinction exists in any case.

Comment: @laurel That is a dud as a duplicate. The answer here is that NO preposition is required (why not is an interesting question). That asks for a list of possible prepositions. Never the twain shall meet. Please undo! Thanks :)